# How to suppress EOF when echoing messages to wall from a script

Tags: bash

In my bash script, I use many `echo "......." | wall` lines to broadcast event notifications as they occur.

However, the resulting output on the console gets unwieldy:

```
Broadcast Message from root@BIGFOOT
        (somewhere) at 16:07 ...

Photo backup started on Mon Oct  7 16:07:55 PHT 2013


Broadcast Message from root@BIGFOOT
        (somewhere) at 16:08 ...

Photo backup successfully finished on Mon Oct  7 16:08:05 PHT 2013


Broadcast Message from root@BIGFOOT
        (somewhere) at 16:08 ...

You may now unplug the Photo Backup HDD.
```

Instead, we'd like it to appear more like the following,

```
Broadcast Message from root@BIGFOOT
        (somewhere) at 16:07 ...

Photo backup started on Mon Oct  7 16:07:55 PHT 2013
Photo backup successfully finished on Mon Oct  7 16:08:05 PHT 2013
You may now unplug the Photo Backup HDD.
```

which is kind of like what would appear in an open write chat session.

Is this possible? If so, how should I modify my script in order to achieve the desired console output?

Comment: `echo -e "line1\nline2\nline3" | wall`?

Comment: `printf` is more portable, as POSIX doesn't specify either `-e` or if escape characters need to be expanded by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `wall` invocation will add the "broadcast message" and blank newline at the top of your code.

As a result, if you want to notify your users at timely intevals (e.g. actually at the start + end of the backup) then you will have to live with the banner message.

As @devnull suggested, you could batch up the messages. One approach would be to declare a script wide variable say `$logmsg` and then have two functions depending on whether it is something you want the user to know eventually or something they want to know *now*

```
function log_message
{
  $logmsg = "$logmsg\n$1"
}

function log_message_now
{
 log_message "$1"
 echo "$logmsg" | wall
 logmsg = ""
}
```

(note I've not actually tested the above, so may need a touch of debugging!)

Answer (score 1):

Use a compound command:

```
{
    echo "line1"
    echo "line2"
    echo "line3"
} | wall
```